# How can I mount something heavy on a wall that's too hard to drill more than 1/2 inch

Tags: walls, drill, mounting, masonry, drill-bit

I am trying to mount a wooden trellis on my living room wall. The house was built in 1890 and later remodeled. Most interior walls are standard drywall with studs, but the exterior walls seem to be brick, as they're hard and produce orange powder when drilled into.

I have successfully drilled into the external brick walls in other rooms, but when I tried to pre-drill the holes for the screws for this project, I could only get about 1/2 to 3/4 inches into the wall before I stopped making progress. I'm using a masonry drill bit but it's just not getting through. The dust is also grey instead of orange so it seems to be a different material than my other brick walls.

What can I do about this? Do I need a special drill bit? Do I need to find another way to mount the trellis?

Comment: What kind of trellis?  What will be hanging on the trellis?  If it's just a light weight decorative one, a few 3/4 inch holes in brick with appropriate fasteners should be plenty.

Comment: As for drilling into unknown material that is impervious to a known good masonry bit ... don't!  It might be a gas pipe or a steel beam.  You should figure out what you're dealing with and why it's there.

Comment: Also, some photos always make it easier to understand the circumstances.

Comment: Grey dust sounds like it could be concrete btw, if it's a steel pipe or beam the drill bit would probably start heating up significantly and deforming.

Comment: Iron/steel could be described as "gray" too. We also don't know that the bit wasn't getting excessively hot either.

Comment: Agreed on the asker needing to clarify this, but whenever I hit metal I get shavings and twirls (not to mention a burning smell) and eventually a visibly very deformed drill bit (if I for some reason keep grinding without checking, yes. did that once)... I wouldn't expect that to be described as 'grey dust'.

Comment: Here's a wild guess.  The plaster in your walls is orange, and you're using a crappy or spent bit that's grinding through the plaster then hitting a cinder block or a brick joint and giving up.    I'd give this guess more credence if you were in a part of the world where orange/brown plaster is common.  Are you?

Comment: When you buy a house that old you should be willing to do some exploratory damage to learn what's behind the walls.  Every wall could be different.  Modern drywall, old drywall, fiber board, plaster on fiber board, plaster on wood lath, plaster on metal lath, plaster on brick, plaster on block, drywall over plaster, two layers of drywall.   And you might have all of these.  ONE WALL might have more than one of these.

Answer (score 0):

If you are indeed hitting brick, a hammer drill with an appropriate masonry drill bit will likely penetrate farther into the wall.

Comment: See @jay613's comment, he should probably first make sure he knows what exactly he's hitting.

Comment: Had to downvote. While technically correct, you're recommending an unsafe practice.

Answer (score 0):

There are masonry drills and masonry drills. Sounds like yours is just a hammer or percussion drill. A *rotary hammer* drill works in a different way, and is far more up to the job. And SDS bits are also made for this job.

If the bit (not a cheap one, I hope!) is getting very hot or even melting, there may be some metal, as in reinforcing, that is just where you're drilling. Try another hole an inch or two to one side.